# Mic not working for Logitech C615HD in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: webcam, microphone, logitech, ubuntu-gnome

I just ordered a brand new Logitech C615HD and connected it to my UbuntuGnome 14.04.1 LTS. In Skype the image works perfectly, but I am not able to get any sound; the mic is not working at all. I am using Skype version 4.3.0.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the Input Setting under `gstreamer-properties` did the trick. If that doesn't work on its own try changing the input settings in the global 'Sound' system setting as well.